# Intermittent hang in WCF service during GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER

Tags: wcf, freeze

I've got an intermittent hang in a WCF service.  Calls that generally take milliseconds start taking upwards of 30 seconds or more to complete before the service recovers.  All of the calls complete successfully however.  New Relic reports that all of the time in the requests are spent in ExecuteRequestHandler.

I enabled failed request tracing on the server for all requests and watched and waited.  When the site started hanging I pulled the traces down and I see the following which is typical:

> 136 - GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER
>
> HeaderName: Content-Length
>   HeaderValue:2237
>   Replace:false
>
> Informational
>
> 273281 ms

All of the other steps in the log are timed at 0ms.  The hanging function varies and when the service is running normally exactly the same functions with exactly the same parameters and response payloads behave perfectly.  It seems that when the site starts hanging, all requests are blocked until is recovers.

Can anyone suggest where I go from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was way out there and pretty annoying from my point of view.  New Relic was saying that the service was hanging in ExecuteRequestHandler and I dove into a rabbit hole trying to diagnose the hang.

The resolution turned out to be to adjust the throttling configuration for the WCF service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="...">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="512" maxConcurrentSessions="3200" maxConcurrentInstances="3712" />
```

Turns out that WCF services are throttled by default even without this entry being present and recently MS increased the default values.  My service was falling over at about 200 rpm (which I don't think is excessive).  The values that I went with are 8x the new defaults and everything works wonderfully now.

Why services are throttled with no indication that this is happening in the default config entries I have no idea.  WCF has been configuration hell and I have resolved never to use it again.  Web API from here on in.

Hope this helps someone one day :)